# how to set value of cell in multiple record - laravel, ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I use AJAX mechanism to set create or modify records in this table:

```
table: 
id | item_type | item_id | creator_id | attitude 
1  | exemplar  | 3       | 33         | 1
2  | exemplar  | 4       | 33         | 0 
3  | exemplar  | 3       | 35         | 1
```

In plain English: there are many exemplars to choose for one user. A given user can only set only one exemplar to value 1. In this particular case Exemplar #3 is active (attitude = 1). I want to set its "attitude" to 0 and in the same controller method where I have the below code.

The below code creates a new record for an exemplar which has never been chosen before, or changes the value of 'attitude column.

```
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $countatt = $exemplar->attitudes()->where('creator_id',  $user_id)->first();
    if (!$countatt)
    {
        $countatt = new Userattitude;
        $countatt->creator_id = $user_id;
        $countatt->item_type = 'exemplar';
        $countatt->item_id = $exemplar_id;
            }
    $countatt->attitude = $value; // $value = 1
    $countatt->save();
```

**Problem to solve:** 
1. how, using the best practices, set all other records of the same user (creator_id) and exemplar_id to 0

My best guess isbe to put the below 4 lines before the code quoted above:

```
$oldactive= Exemplar::where('creator_id', $user_id)->where(exemplar_id, $exemplar_id)->first();

$zeroing_attitude= $oldactive->attitudes()->first(); 
$zeroing_attitude->attitude = 0;
$zeroing_attitude->save();
```

;

2. The above solution works only in case when there is only one exemplar with value of 'attitude' set to 1. But in the future I want to allow users to have multiple exemplars active. I am not familiar with Eloquent enough to rewrite the logic for multiple active Exemplars.
3. Sometimes there will be no active Exemplars set, which means that this collection would be empty

   $oldactive= Exemplar::where('creator_id', $user_id)->where(exemplar_id,     $exemplar_id)->first();

How should I skip executing the rest of the code in such case? By adding IF as below?

```
if($oldactive) {}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The `first()` method will only ever return one record. So `$oldactive->attitudes()->first()` will only ever get you the first record from the collection.

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote. 
I have no idea how to process multiple records which need to have the 'attitude' set to '0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$oldactive= Exemplar::where('creator_id', $user_id)->where(exemplar_id,$exemplar_id)->first();

foreach($oldactive->attitudes() as $zeroing_attitude){ 
    $zeroing_attitude->attitude = 0;
    $zeroing_attitude->save();
}
```

Comment: in some cases there will be no Exemplar set to '1'
May I also ask how to skip the function if no record was found when declaring $oldactive? Something like if($oldactive) ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Sorry.

Comment: rephrased and put as 3rd question in my initial post

Comment: Eloquent returns an `isEmpty()` method on collections which returns `true` when the collection contains no records. so you could do `if( ! $oldactive->isEmpty() ){//collection is not empty, do stuff}`